# Tracking results between different projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I test some software that has different releases running concurrently.  This is in the usual "LTS" "Release", and "Unstable" versions.  We have a third-party test suite that we like to run on all three versions. Because it is third-party, there are expected failures in the builds that execute the suite.

Currently, we have Jenkins set up with a different project for each of the point releases for each of the three versions.  It is easy for us to track the results of the test suite on the same project, but that limits us to just the point release.  We want to be able to compare and get trends for the test suite between the three versions as well as crossing the point releases.  We want to know if the project for LTS 3.2 has overall more failures than the project for LTS 3.3.

I'm not seeing an obvious plugin for graphing the number of pass/fails between different Jenkins projects, is there a method for doing this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a plugin like you describe. But you might try using multi-configuration / matrix projects. Takes a fair bit to set up custom axes like you're describing, but it does make it easier to present different sets of results in a single page. It also aggregates results nicely, which you might be able to use as a stop-gap: you can present one project's results compared to the aggregate or mean results.

Comment: Turns out there's [an issue with downstream project aggregation](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7976), but it works for me if the results are from matrix jobs directly, rather than from downstream builds.